# How to click a button in nested div?

Tags: watir-webdriver

I am new to Watir,and I met trouble when I tried to click the "Add" button in a website. Here is source code:

```
<div class="page_and_btn">
    <div>
        <a href="javascript:addUser();" class="myBtn">
         <em>Add</em></a>
    </div>
```

So far,I tried any way I can find,but just got an exception:`unable to locate element`.
Here are the code I have tried:

```
ie.div(:class,"myBtn").click  
ie.link(:class,"myBtn").click 
ie.link(:text,"Add").click 
ie.button(:text,"Add").click
```

Please tell me what should I do?

Comment: Try `ie.div(:class => "myBtn").click`

Comment: `ie.link(:class,"myBtn").click` works for me given the sample HTML. You might want to check the usual problems - iframes, dynamic loading, etc. I had compiled a [list of common problems/solutions in the Watirways book](https://leanpub.com/watirways/read#leanpub-auto-unknownobjectexception---unable-to-locate-element).

Comment: Thanks for all your answers.I tried     ie.div(:class => "myBtn").click and    ie.link(:class, "myBtn").click again,but did not work.Then I added 10 sleep seconds to make sure this element had finished loading,but it didn't work either.Now,I am completely at  at sea...

Answer (score 0):

You can write short selector
`ie.em(:text => 'Add').click`
 but better will be write long
`ie.div(:class => 'page_and_btn').em(:text => 'Add').click`

very useful method flash
what show element on page
`ie.div(:class => 'page_and_btn').em(:text => 'Add').flash`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.But I got an exception :unable to locate element, using {:class=>"page_and_btn", :tag_name=>"div"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException).I'm going crazy...

Comment: for debugging I use ripl  
https://github.com/cldwalker/ripl
`gem install ripl`  

my debugging script looks like:
require 'ripl'
require 'ripl/multi_line'

first part of script
Ripl.start :binding => binding #this line stopped you script and runed ripl 

ended part of script

Comment: Thanks again.But I don't understand you well.Does that mean I must install gems "ripl" and "ripl/multi_line"?If it does,I do intall these gems ,but only get the same exceptions.

Comment: Thanks Stepan.Finally I found there are several classes named "myBtn" on this page,developer modified class name and my script worked.I don't known whether it is the reason,and it's so strange.Anyhow,it is resolved.Thanks for your advise, from what I know the useful shell ripl.

Answer (score 0):

ie.link(:class,'myBtn').click works fine for me.Still you are not able to proceed further,try below code.
ie.div(:class,'page_and_btn').link(:class,'myBtn').em(:text,'Add').click

Comment: Thanks for your help.I tried your code,but only got this exception:
    unable to locate element, using {:class=>"page_and_btn", :tag_name=>"div"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)